# What kind of white liquid is in the jar?

Tags: plot-explanation, servant

From *Servant* S02E01,

> **Julian:** *You see this? This could put us away for 20 years.*

[image]

What is inside that jar? How could that liquid put them away for 20 years? What's going on in this scene?

Comment: Yes a screenshot would definitely help but additional context would be more useful.

Comment: I've not seen the show, but a very quick scan through the episode synopsis would suggest that the characters are worried about being arrested for kidnapping a baby or having a baby in the house. The presence of what looks like baby milk would presumably give the game away that they've got a real baby

Answer (score 2):

It's milk in a baby bottle.

There is a point in the series where Julian and his brother-in-law Sean come to believe that the baby is possibly/probably a baby Leanne kidnapped. If they keep silent and keep the baby, they could be charged as accessories to the crime of kidnapping, so they start searching for news of missing babies.

Julian, being the more dramatic of the two, holds up the baby's formula milk and equates it with getting caught with a kidnapped baby.